# Full form of VCAP

Tags: vmware, cloud-foundry

So I know what VCAP_APPLICATIONS and VCAP_SERVICES is on CloudFoundry.

But my question is anecdotally what is the full form of VCAP? Does it have to do anything with VMWare. (Considering its history)

I know it's not a technical question, but pretty curious as to why was this abbreviation chosen, or even if it is an abbreviation at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The acronym VCAP was used internally at VMWare before they chose to reuse the “Cloud Foundry” trademark they had acquired from another project earlier. VCAP stood for VMWare Cloud Application Platform.

I do not know why we’ve never added CF_ prefixed duplicate variables to the ones you mentioned. Somethings just make interesting trivia :)